# Using "whether .. or" in negated sentence

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, negation, neither-nor, either-any

I have a sentence like this:

> .. and have no students whether from the same city or others at all

Is it correct? Or would using `neither` as below seems better:

> .. and have no students neither from the same city nor others at all

Comment: Doesn't this simply mean *have no students*? Why bother mentioning cities in the first place, if it boils down to the shorter statement?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this. Sometimes I have to put an example to maintain privacy of the actual text. This time I did not get it right. May be the corrected post now sounds better.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's *groups* or *cities* (or anything). If there are none from the same X or any other X, it still just means there are none . . .

Comment: Note that by changing the wording in your question, you've left the single answer here slightly "stranded." People won't understand why the word *city* was used in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [either...or](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/grammatica/grammatica-britannico/linking-words-and-expressions/either-or):

> ...and have no students *either* from the same city *or* other cities.

Comment: You can easily use *neither . . .nor* if you wish. You just need to remove the initial negation so that it makes sense: *and have students from neither the same city nor other cities*. You could also use *whether*: *and have no students, whether from the same city or other cities*. All of them are fine, so long as the sentences are constructed appropriately around them.